# Dojo: BorderContainer and ContentPanes not working inside of a custom widget template

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I am trying to create some custom templated widgets with dijit.layout objects (BorderContainer, ContentPane) in the template, and I just can't get it to work. Maybe SO can steer me in the right direction... here's my code so far:

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        html, body, #page {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            isDebug: false,
            parseOnLoad: true,
            baseUrl: './',
            modulePaths: {'test' : '.'}
        };
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script>
    dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer');
    dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
    dojo.require('test.testWidget');
    dojo.ready(function() {
        var widget = new test.testWidget({}, 'widgetGoesHere');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <div id='widgetGoesHere'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**testWidget.js**

```
dojo.provide('test.testWidget');
dojo.require('dijit._Widget');
dojo.require('dijit._Templated');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
dojo.declare('test.testWidget', [ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],  {
    templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl('test', 'testWidget.html'),
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    
    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
```

**testWidget.html**

```
<div id="page" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" liveSplitters="true" design='sidebar' style="height:100%;">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region='center'>
        test center
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region='left' style="width:50%">
        test left
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the rather code-verbose post, but I dont know *why* it doesnt work so I can't really describe my problem in just words.

The jist is I want two panes, a 'left' (region='center' in this case) pane, and a 'right' pane that I can put widget content in. The above code simply renders the text in the divs with no panes at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mixin the following in my custom widgets :

```
dijit.layout._LayoutWidget, dijit._Templated, dijit._Container
```

Container allows you to contain other dijits like BorderContainer.
Templated allows you to put your widget markup in a html template.
LayoutWidget allow you to get all the dijit layout and resize goodies.

If you are using dojo 1.4, templatePath can/should now be:

```
templateString : dojo.cache("test", "testWidget.html")
```

In your template you need a top level containerNode (this gets replaced by the dojo parser on widget creation I think) so testWidget's template would become:

```
<div dojoAttachPoint="containerNode" style="height:100%;">
<div id="page" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" liveSplitters="true" design='sidebar' style="height:100%;width:100%;" dojoAttachPoint="subContainerWidget">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region='center'>
            test center
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region='left' style="width:50%">
            test left
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question, what are you using the dojoAttachPoints containerNode and subContainerNode for? This definitly points me in the right direction, its just not quite working 100%

Comment: I reference these nodes in my widget code, e.g.

startup : function () {
        this.subContainerWidget.startup();
        this.inherited(arguments);
    },

Remeber to call the inherited versions of resize and startup and remeber to call startup on your custom widget.