# Dojo 1.7: BorderContainer and ContentPanes not working inside of a custom widget template

Tags: dojo

This is similar to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102594/dojo-bordercontainer-and-contentpanes-not-working-inside-of-a-custom-widget-tem) already on here but I'm using Dojo 1.7. So, I can't get  BorderContainer and ContentPanes working inside of a custom widget template. It's driving me mad. I tried adding the mixins suggested in the other post and it didn't work.

So I have two examples. The first is a single page using dojo declaratively and it works fine. The second example is exactly the same page but I use a widget to embed the template. It renders the widgets but they are all stuck together in the top right corner. Same page, same styles. BUT, when i resize the browser window the page takes shape. There are still bits missing but it's better

- [screenshot here for first example using dojo declaratively](http://cl.ly/2i3s3e39031J0E3r0r2c)
- [screenshot here for second example using a widget](http://cl.ly/0L3y1v0X2o1S1O2K0T41)
- [screenshot here for second example after resizing the browser
  window](http://cl.ly/1A2D3P2g2w281J2O372z). Still not the same as the first example but better.

Many thanks

**This is the first example, which works**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo: Application Controller</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/tag/widgets/BorderWidget/css/demo.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/tag/widgets/BorderWidget/css/style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">

    <!-- Configure Dojo -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var djConfig = {
        isDebug : true,
        parseOnLoad : true
      };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div style="height:100%">
      <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div class="centerPanel" id="tabs" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center', tabPosition: 'bottom'">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'About'">
            <h2>Flickr keyword photo search</h2>
            <p>
              Each search creates a new tab with the results as thumbnails
            </p>
            <p>
              Click on any thumbnail to view the larger image
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
          <div class="searchInputColumn">
            <div class="searchInputColumnInner">
              <input id="searchTerms" placeholder="search terms">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="searchButtonColumn">
            <button id="searchBtn">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And this is second example using a widget**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo: Application Controller</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/tag/widgets/BorderWidget/css/demo.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/tag/widgets/BorderWidget/css/style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">

    <!-- Configure Dojo -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var djConfig = {
        isDebug : true,
        parseOnLoad : true,
        paths : {
          'tag' : '../tag/widgets/BorderWidget'
        }
      };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require('tag.Widget');

      dojo.ready(function() {
        new tag.Widget().startup();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">

  </body>
</html>
```

**This is the widget code**

```
define('tag/Widget', 
[
  'dojo', 
  'dijit/_Widget', 
  'dijit/_TemplatedMixin', 
  'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
  'dijit/layout/BorderContainer',
  'dijit/layout/TabContainer',
  'dijit/layout/ContentPane'
], 
function(d) {
  //The widget contructor will be returned
  return d.declare('tag.Widget', 
  [
    dijit._Widget, 
    dijit._TemplatedMixin, 
    dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin
  ], 
  {
    templateString : d.cache("tag", "templates/template.html"),

    postCreate : function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      var domNode = this.domNode;
    },

    startup : function(args) {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.placeAt(dojo.doc.body);
    }


  });
});
```

**This is the template for the widget**

```
<div style="height:100%">
  <div id="appLayout" class="demoLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
    <div class="centerPanel" id="tabs" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center', tabPosition: 'bottom'">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'About'">
        <h2>Flickr keyword photo search</h2>
        <p>
          Each search creates a new tab with the results as thumbnails
        </p>
        <p>
          Click on any thumbnail to view the larger image
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
      <div class="searchInputColumn">
        <div class="searchInputColumnInner">
          <input id="searchTerms" placeholder="search terms">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="searchButtonColumn">
        <button id="searchBtn">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to create layout is not using templated widgets but to do it programatically. I didn't actually find this anywhere but I also couldn't find anyone who was which lead me to doing it like this;

```
// view
define('tag/views/CampaignTest/layout', [
  'dojo',
  'dbp/widgetStore',
  'dijit/layout/BorderContainer',
  'dijit/layout/TabContainer',
  'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
  'dojo/NodeList-manipulate'
],

function(dojo, widgetStore, BorderContainer, TabContainer, ContentPane) {
  return {
    create : function (layoutName) {
      var deferred = new dojo.Deferred(),
          add = dojo.partial(widgetStore.add, layoutName);

      dojo.query("body").prepend("<div id='appLayout' class='demoLayout'></div>");

      var appLayout = add(
        new BorderContainer({
          design: "headline"
        }, dojo.byId("appLayout"))
      );


      // create the TabContainer
      var contentTabs = add(
        new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
          region: "center",
          id: "contentTabs",
          tabPosition: "bottom",
          "class": "centerPanel",
          href: "contentCenter.html"
        })
      );

      // add the TabContainer as a child of the BorderContainer
      appLayout.addChild( contentTabs );

      // create and add the BorderContainer edge regions
      appLayout.addChild(
        add(
          new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
            style : "height:50px",
            region: "top",
            id : "top",
            "class": "edgePanel",
            content: "Header content (top)"
          })
        )
      );

      appLayout.addChild(
        add(
          new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
            style : "height:50px",
            region: "top",
            id : "top2",
            "class": "edgePanel",
            content: "Next content (top)"
          })
        )
      );

      appLayout.addChild(
        add(
          new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
              region: "left",
              id: "leftCol",
              "class": "edgePanel",
              content: "Sidebar content (left)",
              splitter: true
          })
        )
      );

      contentTabs.addChild(
        add(
          new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
            title: "Start"
          }, dojo.byId("startContent"))
        )
      );

      // not even sure this is necessary but I
      // check to make sure layout has finished
      (function check(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          appLayout.domNode ? deferred.resolve() : check();
        }, 10);
      })();


      appLayout.startup();

      return deferred;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Did you check @skython answer? It works for me with a templated widget and it's überkool :)

Answer (score 4):

You might need to explicitly call startup on the BorderContainer and ContentPane layout widgets in your own `startup()` method.  Also you probably want to always have `this.inherited(arguments)` in any of the widget lifecycle methods if you are overriding  and inheriting method.

```
startup : function(args) {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    //console.log('asdasd')
    dojo.empty("body");
    this.placeAt('body');

    this.subContainerWidget.startup();
    //I think the border container will automatically call startup on its children 
    //(the content panes), but you may also need to call startup on them.
}
```

Also, as @missingno mentioned, you probably don't want to be emptying the `<body>` and replacing it during widget startup, as a general reusability thing.

Comment: Hi Buffalo, sorry about the delayed response. I don't normally take that long to respond. Dojo is rendering the widgets but they don't look the same. I will edit my original post.

Comment: +1 for the helpful response. I read a post by a dojo contributor on the dojo site who said that using widget templates to create layout wasn't the done thing and didn't work very well. Sadly he didn't say what was correct way so I created the layout programatically and it woked fine. Kind of.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem with a custom Widget and BorderContainers within and it finally worked after I inherited BorderContainer instead BaseWidget or _Widget. 
Hope that also helps in your case!

Comment: Excellent - could be a rule that you inherit from the top element of your template if it's a templated widget, so that it will react accordingly.

Comment: @unludo How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating my templated custom widgets which contain BorderContainers with a surrounding `div` (because I couldn't get a top-level BorderContainer to work), like so:

```
<div style="height: 100%;">
<div style="height: 100%;" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
     data-dojo-attach-point="bc"
     data-dojo-props="design: 'headline', gutters: false">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
    </div>
</div>
```

I had the exact same layout problems (BorderContainer would only layout correctly after page resize), until I realized (thanks to the answer by [John Brinnand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1118155/john-brinnand) above) that I need to forward any `resize` calls from dijit to the "inner" BorderContainer. So what I did was to implement a `resize` method in my widget (`"bc"` is the BorderContainer widget, brought in via `data-dojo-attach-point` as seen in the above code):

```
        resize: function () {
        this.bc.resize(arguments);
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
```

and lo and behold: everything works fine.
(I'm using dojo 1.9, but this should work for dojo >= 1.7)

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for sharing.  I'm having the same problem and tried your solution.  However, the resize function I've created on my widget isn't being called.  Do you have to wire it up some way, or inherit a particular class (I'm inheriting _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin).  thanks!

Comment: @Simon: sorry, late reply... but no, I'm also just inheriting _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin and _WidgetsInTemplateMixin. Did you `startup()` your widget?

Answer (score 1):

BorderContainer is a layout widget that needs to be dinamically sized. You have overwritten the startup method and I'd bet this is at least one of the problems.

Since your startup method contents aren't really startupy, I'd suggest you just try removing or renaming it (to expose the original startup).

```
d.declare(...)|{
    ...
    toFullScreen: function(){
        dojo.empty("body");
      this.placeAt('body');
    }
}

var w = new FlickApiView({...});
w.toFullScreen();
w.startup();
```

---

**Edit** (for the new problem):

I find

```
startup : function(args) {
  this.inherited(arguments);
  this.placeAt(dojo.doc.body);
}
```

to be suspicious, since all the resizing is done in the this.inherited part before the widget is actually placed (so the resizing doesn't work initially)

You could try switching the order here but I think it is better to just remove the startup method entirely and change the main to

```
var w  = new tags.Widget();
w.placeAt(dojo.body());
s.startup();
```

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I've not been able to respond. Anyway, your tip is helpful but it still doesn't work. I'm going to edit my post above. Dojo is rendering the widgets but they are completely unformatted.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the response missingno. I worked out a way and posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

The construction and layout of widgets has changed in dojo 1.7. There is an inherent order which is this: construct a widget, add it to it's parent, startup, resize. Prior to 1.7 the sequence of actions for starting a widget was different.

In your example:

- Construct the BorderContainer: var bc= new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({...});
- Add it to it's parent: parent.addChild or parent.appendChild (bc)
- start it up: bc.startup();
- resize it: bc.resize();

The same sequence will apply to children of the border container:

- Construct a content pane: var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({...});
- Add it to it's parent: bc.addChild (cp1);
- Start up the content pane: cp1.startup(); // may not be necessary, but it doesn't hurt
- Resize the content pane: cp1.resize(); // may not be necessary, but it doesn't hurt
- Restart the border container: bc.startup();  // this is important.
- Resize the border container: bc.resize();   // critically important: without it, the layout does not render.

It may seem redundant to start a container that has already started. And you can play with this sequence to find what is or is not necessary. However, the resize() is critical. Without it the layout is not sized correctly and will not render.

Note: this example implies programmatic construction and wire-up of dojo widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing BorderContainer instead of _Widget as [suggested by skython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915364/dojo-1-7-bordercontainer-and-contentpanes-not-working-inside-of-a-custom-widget/8908783#8908783) seemed to fix most issues. A few glitches remained like some borders not being drawn when initially drawing the widget, so I called `resize()` on the child  widgets from the `startup()` method. Note immediately calling resize from the startup method does not work, but using `setTimeout()` with 0 delay works:

```
startup : function(args) {
    // Hack to force widget to initially draw properly.
    array.forEach(this.getChildren(), function(elem, id) {
        setTimeout(elem.resize, 0);
    });

    this.inherited(arguments);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled 4 hrs to finally get it to work with both declarative and programmatic ways. The key is that you have to call the yourBorderContainerObj.startup() or .resize() after its dom element is in place(visible?).

I was trying to create a templated widget which contains a BorderContainer and a few ContentPanes, and placing it in a Dialog. First I couldn't get the BorderContainer and ContentPanes to show properly when the dialog shows, they were initialized and assigned correct class names, but the css effects weren't seem to be applied.

I get the templated widget to work by doing this in the widget:

```
resize: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.myBorderContainerObj.resize();
}
```

That is it. Then the BorderContainer and the ContentPanes all work as they should.

BTW, I'm using 1.8.3.